# How to establish SSL connection with DB (SQL Server, PG), in a driver agnostic way?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, ssl

I have an application that connects with a Database. The DB could be SQL Server, PG, etc. I need to configure the application to use SSL now.

I am using hibernate and configuring the datasources accordingly. I am using `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` as of now.

I understand that in order to connect to SQL Server using SSL, I need to use `SQLServerDataSource`. But then it would not work if someone decides to use PG database.

Is there any way to configure the individual datasources dynamically? Or is there a common datasource that I can use irrespective of the jdbc driver (mssql or pg) provided at the runtime?

Passing the JVM parameters like `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`  modifying the jdbc connection string are not an option.

I am using Spring (mostly XML configs) to bootstrap the application.

Comment: It would be useful to know how is your application bootstrapped. Are you using Spring, Micronaut, Dropwizard or some other framework? Each of the ones I mentioned provide a way to change the used class based on configuration, but it will look a little bit different.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring you can replace the used data source class using [profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

The key idea is that you can provide multiple definition of the same bean. Those definitions would be enclosed in separate `<beans>` element with different profile attribute.

```
<beans profile="embedded-db">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>
<beans profile="sql-server">
    <!-- Configuration of you SQL Server data source -->
</beans>
<beans profile="postgresql">
    <!-- Configuration of you PostgreSQL data source -->
</beans>
```

When running the application the configuration property `spring.profiles.active` needs to be set to choose one or more of the profiles.

Unfortunately, modern Spring documentation doesn't provide much help in setting up XML configs. I think they are now considered legacy.